# Beautiful Soup error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the beautiful soup module to scrape the title of a list of web pages saved in a csv. The script appears to work fine, but once it reaches the 82nd domain it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup.py", line 31, in <module>
    print soup.title.renderContents() # 'Google'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'renderContents'
```

I'm fairly new to python so I'm not sure I understand the error, would anyone be able to clarify what's going wrong?

my code is:

```
import csv
import socket
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

debuglevel = 0

timeout = 5

socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout) 
domains = csv.reader(open('domainlist.csv'))
f = open ('souput.txt', 'w')
for row in domains:
domain = row[0]
req = Request(domain)
try:
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    print domain
except HTTPError, e:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
    print 'Error code: ', e.code
except URLError, e:
    print 'We failed to reach a server.'
    print 'Reason: ', e.reason
else:
    # everything is fine
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    print soup.title # '<title>Google</title>'
    print soup.title.renderContents() # 'Google'
    f.writelines(domain)
    f.writelines("  ")
    f.writelines(soup.title.renderContents())
    f.writelines("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As maozet said, your problem is that title is None, you can check for that value to avoid the issue like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

if soup.title != None:
    print soup.title # '<title>Google</title>'
    print soup.title.renderContents() # 'Google'
    f.writelines(domain)
    f.writelines("  ")
    f.writelines(soup.title.renderContents())
    f.writelines("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! that appears to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

What if a page doesn't have a title???
I had this problem once....just put the code in try except or check for a title.

Comment: That...makes a lot of sense! I'll try and figure out how to do that now :)

Comment: I guess it should be nicer to check for None, like `if soup.title != None:` and then do your thing

Comment: I have tried adding exceptions none,nonetype but neither work, I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but reading a couple of related questions and googling helped me through. Here is what i would suggest to handle specific errors such as NoneType:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://webpage.com').read())
scrapped = soup.find(id='whatweseekfor')

if scrapped == None:
    # command when encountering an error eg: print none

elif scrapped != None:
    # command when there is no None type error eg: print scrapped.get_text()
```

Good luck!